# remove "ال" from all string in arab word

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to remove "ال" from every arabic string thats contains "ال"

I'm trying to do this by using this code but its only delete "ال" from the first word:

```
input      : الغيث الغيث الغيث
output     : غيث الغيث الغيث
what i need: غيث غيث غيث
```

```cs
string[] prefixes = { "ال", "اَلْ", "الْ", "اَل" };
 
foreach (string prefix in prefixes)
{
    if (text.StartsWith(prefix))
    {
        text = text.Substring(prefix.Length);
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Are you familiar with how RTL text works in .NET `String` values?

Comment: Why not just use `text = text.Replace( prefix, "" );` ? (and rename `prefix` to `substr`)

Comment: No I'm not familiar with RTL

Comment: Do not use "StartsWith", then. You need to process the whole string.

Comment: I tried this "text = text.Replace( prefix, "" );" and its work thanks man

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to work with *words* not just `Replace` every occurrence, you may want *regular expression* to match words, e.g.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

string input = "الغيث الغيث الغيث";
string[] prefixes = { "ال", "اَلْ", "الْ", "اَل" };

// \b - word boundary - we are looking for prefixes only
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @$"\b({string.Join("|", prefixes)})", "");
```

Let's have a look:

```
Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, input, output));
```

Output:

```
الغيث الغيث الغيث
غيث غيث غيث
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex:

```
\b\u0627(?:\u0644\u0652?|\u064e\u0644\u0652?)
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uzcXNN/1).

And this is the C# code that does what you want:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string input = @"الغيث الغيث الغيث الغيث

اَلغيث اَلغيث اَلغيث اَلغيث

اَلْغيث اَلْغيث اَلْغيث اَلْغيث

الْغيث الْغيث الْغيث الْغيث
";

      string pattern = @"\b\u0627(?:\u0644\u0652?|\u064e\u0644\u0652?)";
      string replacement = "";
      string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);
      
      Console.WriteLine("Original String: {0}", input);
      Console.WriteLine("\n\n-----------------\n\n");
      Console.WriteLine("Replacement String: {0}", result);                             
   }
}
```

See [C# code demo](https://tio.run/##jVHBSsNAEL3vVww5JdCWUqpCg1SQ3hShFbzkso1DWdhuwu5GIjU3Tx48@BMe/AO/JPmauLttJFGpmUN23r59bzIzsRrGicS6zhQTG1g9Ko3bkLTR6BZzPVriJuNULvJUolIsESokJM3WnMUQc6oULHK6TTmSHQGAA6M01eZ4SNg9XFMm/MCS7oUJpaUtw0SaaTiHC698r57Lz@ql/ID/UkJM/tomeoBGVL11yH7QiTtkD0A8M6ZOtynVGqVw/UbrKBufTs78@cwm06n9nkzmTw5h5y4wTh0jiSmnMW5R2OF5v2mVccuYzWFu9ude@27Yg@YvBm2XoHE4HJdmyQnH0Z1kGq@YQN@7kWzDBOWwckVmsBsX3mC/wW/5H7pIRGL4M@yld0y1bHXYLbhvLgjhWFjjghR1/QU).